# How to responsive scale existing App made in px units

Tags: javascript, css, svelte

I have a existing App where all units are made in px.
The thing was done with poorly responsivenes, but i don't want to change the whole thing now.

Im pretty new to Svelte, but saw there is a possibility to collect the clientWith and height dynamically from the svelte:window element.

Is there a way to apply this dnamically via transform: scale(?,?) css? so that with and height allways use the whole display of a given device.

I use this configuration:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^17.0.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^11.0.0",
    "rollup": "^2.3.4",
    "rollup-plugin-copy-assets": "^2.0.3",
    "rollup-plugin-css-only": "^3.1.0",
    "rollup-plugin-livereload": "^2.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-svelte": "^7.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-terser": "^7.0.0",
    "svelte": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@rollup/plugin-json": "^4.1.0",
    "convert-csv-to-json": "^1.3.3",
    "d3": "^7.4.4",
    "miragejs": "^0.1.45",
    "mock-socket": "^9.1.5",
    "sirv-cli": "^2.0.0",
    "svelte-i18n": "^3.4.0",
    "svelte-keyboard": "^0.5.5",
    "svelte-navigator": "^3.2.2",
    "svelte-preprocess-sass": "^2.0.1",
    "ws": "^8.9.0"
  }
```

To collect the dimesions, i tryed to use:

```
<script>
  let scale = 1;
  let innerHeight = 800;
  let innerWidth = 1024;

  $: scale = Math.min((innerWidth ? innerWidth : 0) / 1024, (innerHeight ? innerHeight : 0) / 800);
</script>

<svelte:window bind:innerWidth bind:innerHeight />
```

Then on the topmost div in the app i try to apply the style like this:

```
  <div on:contextmenu|preventDefault style={bind({ transform: `scale(${scale})` })}>
```

But i keep receiving this error:

```
index.mjs:362 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'insertBefore')
    at insert (index.mjs:362:12)
    at insert_dev (index.mjs:2011:5)
    at Object.mount [as m] (Router.svelte:197:1)
    at mount_component (index.mjs:1827:26)
    at Object.mount [as m] (Route.svelte:117:24)
    at Object.update [as p] (Route.svelte:98:14)
    at update (index.mjs:1093:36)
    at flush (index.mjs:1060:13)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So i managed to get it running for Svelte:

```
  <div class="zoom" bind:clientHeight={cw} bind:clientWidth={ch}>
    <div class="app" on:contextmenu|preventDefault style={scale}>
```

```
  .zoom {
    position: relative;
    transform-origin: top left;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
  }

  .app {
    min-width: 1000px;
    min-height: 600px;

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    position: relative;
    transform-origin: top left;
    background-color: $color--black;
    white-space: pre-line; //adds newline possibility to svelte-i18n plugin
  }
```

```
  //screenscaling below 1024 / 600
  $: scaleX = ch < 1024 && cw >= 600;
  $: scaleY = ch >= 1024 && cw < 600;
  $: scaleXY = ch < 1024 && cw < 600;
  $: rotation = ch < cw;
  $: scale = scaleXY
    ? `transform: scale(${((100 / 1024) * ch) / 100 + hFix},${((100 / 600) * cw) / 100 + wFix}`
    : scaleX
    ? `transform: scale(${((100 / 1024) * ch) / 100 + hFix},1)`
    : scaleY
    ? `transform: scale(1,${((100 / 600) * cw) / 100 + wFix})`
    : `transform: scale(1,1)`;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS to set the `width` and `height` to be proportional to the viewport using `vh` and `vw`. Both of these are great since you don't need to get the viewport size with JS anymore.

[Check it out on MDN.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units) Both properties express a percentage of the current viewport height/width.

Comment: Thanx for the hint i had a look on it.
I think what i miss is something like this..

transform: scale(calc(1024px / 100vw), calc(600px / 100vh));